# Plotting Histogram with given x and y values

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram that lines up every x value with the y value on the plot. I have tried to use multiple resources, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything. This is the best way I could code to make a histogram.

```
x = (1,2,3,4,5)
y = (1,2,3,4,5)

h=plt.hist(x,y)
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 6])
plt.show()
```

I want a graph that looks like the image below without those a's on x-axis:

[image]

Comment: Can you please update your code to include the library you are using?

Comment: None. I am not using any libraries. The graph does show up, but is messed up. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: `import plt` causes ImportError: No module named 'plt'

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Okay so I am guessing you have installed matplotlib just because I recognise the syntax. plt is not a module available in a standard python installation. Please include the import statement above your code

Comment: try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` that's when I normally see plt being used

Comment: This looks like you would like a bar chart as opposed to a histogram ( if you already have bin, frequency values) and you just want to plot them together. Is that correct?

Answer (score 27):

From your plot and initial code, I could gather that you already have the bin and the frequency values in 2 vectors x and y. In this case, you will just plot a bar chart of these values, as opposed to the histogram using the plt.hist command. You can do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (1,2,3,4,5)
y = (1,2,3,4,5)

plt.bar(x,y,align='center') # A bar chart
plt.xlabel('Bins')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
for i in range(len(y)):
    plt.hlines(y[i],0,x[i]) # Here you are drawing the horizontal lines
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart with bins and values]